# append key value pair to array at a particular index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a `serializeArray()` data populated using:

```
var compArr = $(':input[name="cc_text"]').serializeArray();
```

`console.log(compArr)` looks like this:

```
0:{name: "cc_text", value: "spring 2016;"}
1:{name: "cc_text", value: "fall 2016;"}
```

I need to add a new entry such as `code: "B007"` and `code: "J007"` into each of the indexes respectively, so that new array looks like:

```
0:{name: "cc_text", value: "spring 2016;", code: "B007"}
1:{name: "cc_text", value: "fall 2016;", code: "J007"}
```

Currently, I have a for loop that looks like this:

```
for(var j = 0; j < countVar; j++)
{
  compArr.push({code: $('#label_text_'+j).text()})
}
```

The result I get looks like this:

```
0:{name: "cc_text", value: "spring 2016;"}
1:{name: "cc_text", value: "fall 2016;"}
2:{code: "B007"}
2:{code: "J007"}
```

When I tried to do something like this inside loop:

```
compArr[j].push({code: $('#label_text_'+j).text()})
```

I get error `compArr[j].push` no push function exists.

Is there a way to achieve this without recreating a new array and reinserting all the data, perhaps by just modifying the how I populate the initial `serializeArray()`

Comment: is `code: "B007" and code: "J007"` from an array too?

Comment: No. It is a label text. The actual text from he label is `B007` and `J007` respectively

Comment: include all relevant code in OP also the correct format of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to add to an object, not push to an array.  Try this:

```
compArr[j].code = $('#label_text_'+j).text();
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your compArr contains objects. It looks like you want to add a 'code' property to each of those objects. To do that, loop through compArr and add the appropriate code to each object.

```
for (var i = 0; i < compArr.length; i += 1) {
    compArr[i].code = $('#label_text_'+i).text();
}
```

The above example assumes you have #label_text_0 and #label_text_1 elements containing your code values.